# Creating / updating locations while creating a checkin in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I'm trying to create/update a location while saving a checkin in my Rails project, but am having trouble.

A Checkin belongs_to :location and, a Location has_many :checkins

I'm using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :location, :allow_destroy => true` in my checkin model, and am trying to create a location when creating a checkin like so:

```
POST "checkin[note]=this-is-great&checkin[user_id]=123&checkin[location_attributes][name]=popeyes&checkin[location_attributes][id]=314" to http://localhost:3000/checkins.json
```

However, everytime I run that, it throws an error saying

> Couldn't find Location with ID=314 for Checkin with ID=

I'm not sure what I'm doing right..? I'd like for it to create the Location with a specific ID if it doesn't exist, and update that same location (according the location_id) if it does exist.

The location table has an id (primary key) and name (varchar)

The checkin table has an id (primary key, auto-increment) and note (varchar)

Anyone successfully work with accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it through curl, but your problem seems to be related to the routes. You are sending a `GET` request which would end up in the `show` action, and you need a `POST` request to reach create/ update actions.

Comment: Well actually that's a simplified version of my request. Should've been more explicit, sorry. In any case I am sending it as POST but it still won't allow me to create a location. The checkin does get created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did to solve the problem:

I changed the id of Locations from primary to primary+auto-increment, and stopped trying to set it manually. Instead of making it the same as the foursquare_id that I was trying to store, I decided to store the foursquare_id separately (in a different column).

My checkin model looks like this:

```
  belongs_to :location, :autosave => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location, :allow_destroy => true

 def autosave_associated_records_for_location
    if Location.find_by_foursquareID(location.foursquareID)
      self.location = Location.find_by_foursquareID(location.foursquareID)
    else
      self.location.save!
      self.location = self.location
    end
  end
```